# Validate Document on insert in Mongodb .net driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, validation

Let us say I have Person data model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to prevent insertion of new document of type Person if another document with same Name and Title was inserted within the last 5 minutes.

So I added CreatedAt and ValidTill.

```
  public class Person
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTill { get; set; }
 }
```

I searched for a mechanism which returns an exception if I try to insert a duplicate (I don't want to update the previous document).

What I think will work for me is:

```
context.People.InsertOne(person, new InsertOneOptions() {
BypassDocumentValidation = !context.People.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Title == person.Title && 
x.Name == person.Name && x.ValidTill > person.CreatedAt).Any()});
```

However when I use it, a duplicate document is still inserted despite that value of BypassDocumentValidation is false, I understand that I need to use:

```
DocumentValidationAction action = DocumentValidationAction.Error;
```

But I could not figure how to pass it to insert.

Comment: what if the same type person with same name and title was inserted 15 or 50 minutes ago?  Is it okay then?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes, it is okay in my case

Comment: you have to first define validator (with appropriate action) on the collection - that's not done in the insert operation, it's a collection modification command).  But validation isn't the way to do this either, since you are prone to race conditions when two inserts happen very close to the same time - there won't be a duplicate when you check but by the time both insert there will be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using document validation, however you can construct an update that does the thing that you want to do.

In `mongo` shell syntax, you do this:

```
now=new Date();
nowMinus5=new Date(now-5*60*1000);
db.collection.update(
    {name:"Asya", title:"Smartie", createdAt:{$gt:nowMinus5}},
    {
        $set:{name:"Asya"},
        $setOnInsert:{createdAt:now}  /* this is where you would put other fields to insert */
    },
    { upsert:true }
)
```

What happens is that if the same `name` and `title` with `createdAt` within 5 minutes is found, then a "no-op" `update` is executed on it (`name` is set to whatever it already is).  If it's not found, then an `insert` (via `upsert`) is executed which can set all the fields you want to set as if it was an `insert`.

Your application can determine which happened by examining the writeResult returned from update and return appropriate message back to the client/user.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple threads creating documents, it's possible for two threads to insert two documents with same name/title around the same time.  You may be able to mitigate that possibility by having a unique index on name,title,createdAt time but then you should set createdAt to some higher granularity than milliseconds, maybe minutes - though it's still possible to have a race condition at minute boundary)